# Clamping values in preference screen

Tags: android

Is there a way to clamp the numerical value entered into a editTextPreference? I'd like to limit a value to say +- 45.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to setting [android:inputType="numberSigned"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType), you would need to setup a [KeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setKeyListener%28android.text.method.KeyListener%29), or [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29), to enforce the min/max values.

Alternatively, you may want to look into one of the existing views that are intended for this type of limited input, such as [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html)

Comment: The number picker looks good, is there any way to get it to work without having to add all of these drawables? Having those in there will double the size of my app!

Comment: What drawables? It's a built-in widget, everything needed for it should already be included on the device...

Comment: Joe, I was referring to dmon's response. I can't seem to figure out how to get a dialog with the numberpicker that actually works from my preference...